# Make UIImage zoom to screen size inside UIScrollViewer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

**Edit: The solution was to add the UIScrollView and UIImageView programmatically. The issue might have been with the auto-constraint option set through Storyboard. So I would like to know how such view could be set in the Storyboard and actually work. Letting this question stand as maybe other people would like to know this.**

I have an UIImageViwer inside a UIScrollViewer. I've found several example for this question online, and I've implemented them as this:

```
func setZoomScale() {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    let widthScale = scrollViewSize.width / imageViewSize.width
    let heightScale = scrollViewSize.height / imageViewSize.height

    let minZoomScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoomScale
    scrollView.zoomScale = minZoomScale
}
```

The issue is that the image does not fit inside the screen size, it's way smaller or bigger.

For instance this landscape image: 
This is the value that UIScrollViewer is reporting

> Min Zoom: 0.12254901960784313 ZOOM: 0.12471373968656897

With a 600x667 point scale the image size is reported as: 
CGSize
  - width : **4896.0**
  - height : **3264.0**

[image: Landscape zooming]

When the image is a portrait this is the result:

> CGSize
>     - width : **1280.0**
>     - height : **1920.0**

[image]

The image is set with this method:

```
self.imageView.image = image
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

var frame = self.imageView.frame;
frame.size = image!.size;
self.imageView.frame = frame;

self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size
self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

self.setZoomScale()
```

If I don't do this the UIImageViewer.size is reported as 600x667 points, making the minimumZoom = 1, and the image is clipped.

Comment: Please can you try content mode ScaleAspectFill or ScaleToFill so you can get the image in first original size and in second same as imageview size.

Comment: I think your code is correct. Did you call `zoomToRect:animated` after all this stuff?

Comment: @Fujia I did not, I'm trying, but the zoomToRect need a CGRect() as parameter, where do I get that CGRect() from?

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA I tried that, but it didn't work...

Comment: Could it be because I have added the UIScrollViewer in my Storyboard and have set the constraint with the "Add Missing Constraints" option?

Comment: @jonas it may be but i'm not sure.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA it worked when the UIScrollViewer was created programmatically. I wonder how it would work when its added with the Storyboard.

Comment: @jonas so finally it worked! so congrets and ya if you found why it worked with programmatically than please tell me i also want to know how it worked.